# How can I test multiple pages in a single Intern test

Tags: intern

Is it possible for a single functional test to handle 2 different pages? For example, when I execute the following test:

```
    return this.remote
           .get(testPage)
           .waitForElementByCssSelector('.alfresco-core-Page.allWidgetsProcessed', 5000)
           .elementByCss('#UNIT_TEST_MODEL_FIELD>DIV.control>TEXTAREA')
              .type(testData)
              .end()
           .elementByCss("#LOAD_TEST_BUTTON")
              .click()
              .sleep(2000)
              .waitForElementByCssSelector('.alfresco-core-Page.allWidgetsProcessed', 5000)
                 .elementByCss("#DD1") 
                 .click()
                 .end();
```

I get the following error:

```
Test main - firstTest - Test1 FAILED on chrome 31.0.1650.57 on LINUX:
Error: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined at null.<anonymous>     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:108:10)
    at /home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/lib/wd.js:769:29
    at signalListener     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:37    :21)
    at signalWaiting     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28    :4)
    at resolve     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:19    2:5)
    at signalDeferred     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:81    :15)
    at signalListener     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:52    :6)
    at signalWaiting     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28    :4)
    at resolve     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:19    2:5)
    at signalDeferred     (/home/dave/ScratchPad/ShareInternTests/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:81    :15)
```

Because of the framework that I'm testing I need to load a "bootstrap" test page which I write the test data into and then POST it to persist a test model into the HTTP session which is then rendered in a resultant page.

However, whilst the first part of the test works fine (I see the test data entered and the next page is submitted, I seem to get the error on the 2nd .waitForElementByCssSelector call. I've tried various permutations but can't get this to work.

If I run a completely second test on the second page then this works fine, but ideally I'd like it all captured within a single test.

Is what I'd like to do possible or do I have to break it into separate tests?

Comment: I've just discovered that by adding an .end() after the .sleep() call it now works.... I've not been able to find any documentation on what .end() does or more importantly when it should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using `setImplicitWaitTimeout` and use the `elementBy*` methods instead of using `waitForElementByCssSelector`. It is more efficient, and should work properly.

A second option is to make sure you call `end` before the second `waitForElementByCssSelector` call; it looks like there is a [defect](https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/119) in the way the `waitForElement` methods are called, where the `#LOAD_TEST_BUTTON` element is being used as the context for the call but `waitForElement` accepts no context.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help with this... I've got my first complete end-to-end test running for our UI framework now. The efficiency tips are greatly appreciated as well.